# SqlBulkCopy problem with new line at the end of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` to import an Excel file with C# and EPPlus on an ASP.NET MVC page. My goal is to import all the rows, compare with existing data and then update the values that do not match. Everything works fine except when dealing with line breaks and line breaks at the end of the data.

`\r\n` becomes `\n` and if at the end, it gets completely ignored, for example:

This "...cerâmica e com tampa removível. \r\n\r\nVersátil, pode ser usada como pote na sua decoração.\r\n\r\nRecomendada para todos os ambientes da casa.\r\n\r\n" becomes "...cerâmica e com tampa removível. \n\nVersátil, pode ser usada como pote na sua decoração.\n\nRecomendada para todos os ambientes da casa."

Searching for the answer I managed to understand that this behaviour is expected, considering that the column's type is `varchar(max)`, is that right?

If so... my problem is that I cannot use a big char column, because it would exceed max row size since I need many of those big size columns.

I need to keep those line breaks at the end of the data and, if possible, would like to keep those in the middle untouched as well.

Is there a way to use `SqlBulkCopy` and alter this behavior to not change the data at all ? I don't know, maybe something in the column mapping ?

Regarding the import process, everything starts with and Excel file. I import that file and convert it to EPPLUS `ExcelPackage` class. Then I convert the `ExcelSheet` with the data to a `DataTable`.

After that I create a temp table on the database. The relevant columns are of the `[VARCHAR](MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL` type. Finally, I use `SqlBulkCopy` to write the data from that `DataTable` into that temp table.

I checked that the data is still untouched while in the `DataTable`. The change happens only when the information is written on the table in the database.

PS I didn't include code because I didn't think it would be relevant to the question. If you guys think other way, please, just let me know.

Comment: `If you guys think other way,` I do.

Comment: Is your complaint, essentially, that "when my bulk loaded data contains line terminators as part of the data, they are being as row  terminators and the data is getting messed up" or is your complaint "my data with windows line endings is being converted to unix line endings by bulk copy" ?